# Convert an element from a jQuery .contents() object to a string or array

Tags: javascript, jquery, type-conversion

I'm trying to do some things with the last bit of text in a paragraph that requires converting it into an array. I know I can grab that last bit using [the .contents() method](https://api.jquery.com/contents/), and then isolating the last element in that object.

But when I try to create an array from that last bit, the only thing preserved is the length! Demo:

```
<p class="orig"><strong>Some bold text</strong> and some other text</p>
<script>
    var bits = $('.orig').contents(); // [strong, text]
    var lastBit = bits[bits.length - 1]; // " and some other text"
    var array = Array.from(lastBit); // [undefined, undefined, . . . undefined]
</script>
```

What am I missing here? Is there any way to capture that last bit of text in a javascript variable or jQuery object? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lastBit variable is not a simple string but rather a [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) object. Use `lastBit.wholeText` or `lastBit.data` for example to get the actual text string.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code.

**1.** `Array.from` method expects the *array-like or iterable object*. But in your case it is string (which is iterable), which would break the string into individual characters and i assume you do not need that behavior.

**2.** `lastBit` is `Node` and you need to get the text Value of the data in that node which can be retrieved by `lastBit.data`. After getting the string value you can  further split using a seperator character like  ' ' to convert into an array.

Following code should work.

```js
var bits = $('.orig').contents(); 
var lastBit = bits[bits.length - 1]; 
var array = lastBit.data.split(' ');
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="orig"><strong>Some bold text</strong> and some other text</p>
```